# How to install libnss-mdns in centos7

Tags: ubuntu, centos, docker, mdns

I have a requirement to migrate a service from Ubuntu image to centos image. I am having problems installing `yum install avahi-daemon libnss-mdns` services. I found the name of avahi-daemon's installation package on centos through [command-not-found website](https://command-not-found.com/avahi-daemon), but I did not find the name of `libnss-mdns`.

Is there any other convenient way to find the installation package names of various services in different servers, at least the `libnss-mdns` package?

I really appreciate any help with this.

Part of the Dockerfile content that needs to be migrated：

```
...
# ubtuntu Dockerfile
RUN set -ex \
 && DEPS="avahi-daemon libnss-mdns" \
 && apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends $DEPS \
 # Disable nss-mdns's two-label limit heuristic so that host names
 # with multiple labels can be resolved.
 # E.g. redis-12000.rediscluster.local, which has 3 labels.
 # (https://github.com/lathiat/nss-mdns#etcmdnsallow)
 && echo '*' > /etc/mdns.allow \
 # Configure NSSwitch to use the mdns4 plugin so mdns.allow is respected
 && sed -i "s/hosts:.*/hosts:          files mdns4 dns/g" /etc/nsswitch.conf \
 # We run a `avahi-daemon` without `dbus` so that we can start it as a
 # non-root user. `dbus` requires root permissions to start. And
 # anyway, there's a way to run `avahi-daemon` without `dbus` so why
 # shouldn't we use it.  https://linux.die.net/man/5/avahi-daemon.conf
 && printf "[server]\nenable-dbus=no\n" >> /etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf \
 && chmod 777 /etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf \
 # We create the directory because when the first time `avahi-daemon`
 # is run, the directory doesn't exist and the `avahi-daemon` must have
 # permissions to create the directory under `/var`.
 && mkdir -p /var/run/avahi-daemon \
 # Change the permissions of the directories avahi will use.
 && chown avahi:avahi /var/run/avahi-daemon \
 && chmod 777 /var/run/avahi-daemon
...
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any other convenient way to find the installation package names of various services in different servers, at least the libnss-mdns package?

1. On the old system, list files contained in the package (using `dpkg -L` or `rpm -ql`) and try to pinpoint the important ones. For libnss-mdns, it's going to be **`libnss_mdns.so.2`**, a "name service" module loaded by glibc.
2. On the new system, use the package manager's "what provides" or "search by file" function, e.g. `yum whatprovides` or `apt-file search`, to determine which package offers that file. (I don't have a CentOS machine to check the result.)